# CENTOS 7 - $PATH incorrect after installing jdk

Tags: bash, path, centos, environment-variables

I'm new with Linux OS and I have installed jdk on centos7.

Now each time I login, I get following error message:

```
/usr/libexec/grepconf.sh: line 5: grep: command not found
-bash: /home/centos/.bash_profile: line 13: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
-bash: /home/centos/.bash_profile: line 13: `export PATH=$PATH:/opt/jdk1.8.0_192/bin:/opt/jdk1.8.0_192/jre/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/centos/.local/bin:/home/centos/bin:/usr/bin/grep>'
```

and all commands are "not found"

I find this post to update path:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/302743/centos-7-all-command-not-found-except-cd

and I update path with this command:

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:bin
```

So now with 
`sudo nano /home/centos/ .bash_profile` command I have following content in bash_profile file:

```
# .bash_profile

# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
fi

 # User specific environment and startup programs

 PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin

 export PATH
 export PATH=$PATH:/opt/jdk1.8.0_192/bin:/opt/jdk1.8.0_192/jre/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/centos/.local/bin:/home/centos/bin:/usr/bin/grep>
```

What is problem ? How can I solve the error described ?

**1rst edit** in order to answer @nautical questions:

Here the content of .bash_profile file :

```
# .bash_profile

# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
        . ~/.bashrc
fi

# User specific environment and startup programs

PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin

export PATH
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/jdk1.8.0_192/bin:/opt/jdk1.8.0_192/jre/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/centos/.local/bin:/home/centos/bin:/usr/bin/grep
```

Here the content of grepconf :

```
#!/bin/sh

case "$1" in
    -c | --interactive-color)
        ! grep -qsi "^COLOR.*none" /etc/GREP_COLORS
        ;;
    *)
        echo >&2 "Invalid / no option passed, so far only -c | --interactive-color is supported."
        exit 1
        ;;
esac
```

**2nd Edit** in order to answer questions in comment :

here ldd /usr/bin/grep command output:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff769b8000)
    libpcre.so.1 => /lib64/libpcre.so.1 (0x00007f0454df3000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f0454a26000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f0454809000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000055ce09e0c000)
```

Here the result of ls -l /lib64/ld*

```
[centos@serveur-1 ~]$ ls -l /lib64/ld*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 163400 Jan 29 18:55 /lib64/ld-2.17.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     10 Feb 20 21:51 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -> ld-2.17.so
```

And each time I logout, then I login,
I get always "command not found" except for some command like for example :

```
java -version
```

So each time I must type "PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:bin/" (answer found on this site) and each time I type echo $PATH, the output is more and more complex :

```
[centos@serveur-1 ~]$ echo $PATH
$PATH:/opt/jdk1.8.0_192/bin:/opt/jdk1.8.0_192/jre/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/centos/.local/bin:/home/centos/bin:/opt/jdk1.8.0_192/bin:/opt/jdk1.8.0_192/jre/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/centos/.local/bin:/home/centos/bin:/usr/bin/grep
```

I suppose $PATH content is bad just after login.

So how can I solved it definitively ?

**Third edit** for @tripleee :
Here .bashrc file content :

```
[centos@serveur-1 ~]$ sudo nano /home/centos/.bashrc
  GNU nano 2.3.1                  File: /home/centos/.bashrc

# .bashrc

# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
        . /etc/bashrc
fi

# Uncomment the following line if you don't like systemctl's auto-paging feature:
# export SYSTEMD_PAGER=

# User specific aliases and functions
```

It talks about /etc/bashrc, so this is its content:

```
[centos@serveur-1 ~]$ sudo nano /etc/bashrc
  GNU nano 2.3.1                   File: /etc/bashrc

# /etc/bashrc

# System wide functions and aliases
# Environment stuff goes in /etc/profile

# It's NOT a good idea to change this file unless you know what you
# are doing. It's much better to create a custom.sh shell script in
# /etc/profile.d/ to make custom changes to your environment, as this
# will prevent the need for merging in future updates.

# are we an interactive shell?
if [ "$PS1" ]; then
  if [ -z "$PROMPT_COMMAND" ]; then
    case $TERM in
    xterm*|vte*)
      if [ -e /etc/sysconfig/bash-prompt-xterm ]; then
          PROMPT_COMMAND=/etc/sysconfig/bash-prompt-xterm
      elif [ "${VTE_VERSION:-0}" -ge 3405 ]; then
          PROMPT_COMMAND="__vte_prompt_command"
      else
          PROMPT_COMMAND='printf "\033]0;%s@%s:%s\007" "${USER}" "${HOSTNAME%%.*}" "${PWD/#$HOM$
      fi
      ;;
    screen*)
      if [ -e /etc/sysconfig/bash-prompt-screen ]; then
          PROMPT_COMMAND=/etc/sysconfig/bash-prompt-screen
      else
          PROMPT_COMMAND='printf "\033k%s@%s:%s\033\\" "${USER}" "${HOSTNAME%%.*}" "${PWD/#$HOM$
      fi
      ;;
    *)
      [ -e /etc/sysconfig/bash-prompt-default ] && PROMPT_COMMAND=/etc/sysconfig/bash-prompt-de$
      ;;
    esac
  fi
  # Turn on parallel history
  shopt -s histappend
  history -a
  # Turn on checkwinsize
  shopt -s checkwinsize
  [ "$PS1" = "\\s-\\v\\\$ " ] && PS1="[\u@\h \W]\\$ "
  # You might want to have e.g. tty in prompt (e.g. more virtual machines)
  # and console windows
  # If you want to do so, just add e.g.
  # if [ "$PS1" ]; then
  #   PS1="[\u@\h:\l \W]\\$ "
  # fi
  # to your custom modification shell script in /etc/profile.d/ directory
fi

if ! shopt -q login_shell ; then # We're not a login shell
    # Need to redefine pathmunge, it get's undefined at the end of /etc/profile
    pathmunge () {
        case ":${PATH}:" in
            *:"$1":*)
                ;;
            *)
                if [ "$2" = "after" ] ; then
                    PATH=$PATH:$1
                else
                    PATH=$1:$PATH
                fi
        esac
    }

    # By default, we want umask to get set. This sets it for non-login shell.
    # Current threshold for system reserved uid/gids is 200
    # You could check uidgid reservation validity in
    # /usr/share/doc/setup-*/uidgid file
    if [ $UID -gt 199 ] && [ "`/usr/bin/id -gn`" = "`/usr/bin/id -un`" ]; 

then
       umask 002
    else
       umask 022
    fi

    SHELL=/bin/bash
    # Only display echos from profile.d scripts if we are no login shell
    # and interactive - otherwise just process them to set envvars
    for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh; do
        if [ -r "$i" ]; then
            if [ "$PS1" ]; then
                . "$i"
            else
                . "$i" >/dev/null
            fi
        fi
    done

    unset i
    unset -f pathmunge
fi
# vim:ts=4:sw=4
```

It's quite difficult to understand this mechanism when you come from "Windows world"...

Comment: *`PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:bin`* -- this is wrong, it lacks a slash before the final `bin`; but none of this explains your symptoms exactly. What's the `PATH` at the end, when you are logged in?

Comment: What ends up running `grepconf`? Are there commands in `.bashrc` which you are not showing?

Comment: all .bash_profile file content is shown

Comment: Yes but it tries to run `.bashrc` too and the code you show doesn't run `grepconf`; so this is currently unreproducible, and there is some code somewhere which you are not showing us. Could you please look again; do you have a file named `.bashrc` in your home directory, and if so, what does it contain?

Comment: The fix for the missing slash is `/bin` not `bin/`

Comment: Whatever ends up putting the text `$PATH` at the beginning of the value is wrong. Do you see `PATH='$PATH` or `PATH=\$PATH` anywhere in your dotfiles? `grep "PATH=[\']" "$HOME"/.[!.]*`

Comment: @tripleee Yes, I found it in /home/centos/, I copy its content to the post.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by updating .bash_profile as following:

```
# .bash_profile

# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
fi

# User specific environment and startup programs 


PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/opt/jdk1.8.0_192/bin:/opt/jdk1.8.0_192/jre/bin

export PATH
```

I'm new with Centos so I hope I will retrieve my 2 points (removed by negative vote):

- I have edited my question and structured it in order to answer questions asked in comments
- I have looked for answer (see link) but I don't understand all instructions so may be difficult to be clear